# Assign string to an array value

Tags: c++

I need to assign a string to an array value:

`char mystr[3] = "Hello";`

But when I run this code on arduino simulator: tinkercad.com, I get this error:

`1:17: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]`

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a programming question, not an Arduino one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked the compiler to allocate 3 `char` of memory, and then you ask it to fill that memory with 6 `bytes` of data (5 characters, plus null-char for termination.)